# php mysql select from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have 2 mysql tables

table1 - Payments

```
id   |  client_id  | payment | date
1  |   4 |        100   |  01.05.2017
2  |   4 |        120   | 05.05.2017
```

table2 - Invoice

```
id |  client_id |  total |  invoice_nr |  date
1  |    4      |   350  |    0001     |  01.03.2017
2  |    4      |   400  |    0002    |  01.04.2017
```

how to display the result like this order by date

```
id   |    date |         payment  |  total |  invoice_nr
1    |    01.03.2017  |     null |    350  |     0001
2    |   01.04.2017  |     null |    400  |     0002
1    |    01.05.2017  |    100    |     null |      null 
2    |    05.05.2017  |    120    |     null |     null
```

I tried in some ways but with errors.

Comment: "I tried in some ways but with errors" what have you tried? What were the errors?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `union all` queries from both tables:

```
SELECT   `id`, `date`, `payment`, NULL AS `total`, NULL AS `invoice_nr`
FROM     `payments`
UNION ALL
SELECT   `id`, `date`, NULL AS `payment`, `total`, `invoice_nr`
FROM     `invoice`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

this works for me

```
SELECT 
table2.id, 
table2.date, 
table2.payment, 
table2.total,  
table2.invoice_nr  
from table1,table2 
where 
table1.id = table2.cliente_id
```

Comment: don't suggest a join method that is over 25 years old use `INNER JOIN ... ON` syntax instead off the comma join... the comma join is harder to hard and eazier to mis that you mean a JOIN.

Comment: This is also just plain wrong. This will produce two rows, not 4 like in the desired result.